# Search engine friend search string using htaccess

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Is it possible to alter my search result url say from this:

```
/search.php?query=Currys
```

To something more search engine friendly and also add to it so that it becomes something like this:

```
/search-results-for-Currys-Voucher-Codes
```

By using htaccess?

Thanks.

Comment: Oh look, a question on the basic use of mod_rewrite – that’s totally new and has never been asked before …

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can probably do something like this by placing this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

# external redirect from actual URL to pretty one
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+search\.php\?query=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /search-results-for-%1? [R=301,L,NE]

# internal forward from pretty URL to actual one
RewriteRule ^search-results-for-(.+?)/?$ /search.php?query=$1 [L,QSA,NC,NE]
```

Then inside `search.php` get your parameters as `$_GET['query']`

Comment: Wasn't sure where to place the slug part in the search file so I removed everything between the ) and /$ and also &slug=$2 just to see if it would do anything but nothing seemed to happen.

Comment: Ok edited to remove slug part. Can you try it now.

Comment: Stil not getting anything.  Test site is here: http://testingstuff.tk/search.php?query=currys

Comment: Oh looks like you want rewrite other way also. Check edited code now.

Comment: Brilliant stuff - working!  Thanks.  Will help a lot.

Comment: There is one more thing.  The spaces in the merchant names are being replaced by this in the url %2520 .  Can htaccess be used to make the url appear with dashes instead?

Comment: Just edited with `NE` flag. Now spaces (`%20`) won't be encoded. For replacing all spaces with hyphen you'll need further rules and that will cause your query to fail since you will need to replace all hyphens with spaces again.

Comment: That looks perfect to me as it is.  Thanks again.

Comment: Great to know. Can you please now upvote and mark the answer as accepted.

Comment: I have spotted a problem.  This works /search.php?query=Pro-10 and it finds the Pro-10 company but with the htaccess code in place /search-results-for-Pro-10 doesn't work as it cuts off at the dash and ends up as /search-results-for-Pro .  This works for all search terms with a dash in it.  Any fix for this plz?

Comment: Yup that did it.  Cheers.  Can update this now as accepted - if I can figure out how ;) .